# Divisibility of the an Element of a Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group. If $g\in G$ has finite order $m$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then show that the order of the element $Hg\in G/H$ is finite and divides $m$.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If $H$ is a normal subgroup, for any $g\in G$, and any $k\in \mathbf Z$, $\;(Hg)^k=Hg^k$.